# Change image with animated gif

Tags: jquery, animation, xhtml

I am trying to change an image with an animated gif.

There are two images.One static and one animated.Once you click the black border box the static image should change to animated one and then after 2 seconds it will go back to static image again.

It works but for some reason sometimes it is not synchronizing properly.Probably due to setimeout function? Not sure though.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer, timer2, timer3;
    $('#targetDIV_three').click(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(timer3);
        srcToGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3.gif";
        srcTonormalGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3_bg.gif";
        $('#divthree_three').attr('src', srcToGif2);
        timer3 = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $("#divthree_three").attr('src', srcTonormalGif2);
        }, 800);
    });

});
```

JSfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/wTKpL/

Comment: What is supposed to happen exactly?

Comment: There are two images.One static and one animated.Once you click the black border box the static image should change to animated one and then after 2 seconds it will go back to static image again.

Comment: for two seconds the 800 should be 2000

Comment: Does the animated gif complete its loop in exactly 2 seconds ?

Comment: The total timeframe of the loop is 1 second that is 1000 made of 30 frames.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `timer3` and not just assign it.

> yes it works for the first time. But if you continue clicking the
>   black border box then you will see it is not ending or starting from
>   the first frame.The animated gif is total 1 second loop.

### UPDATED

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZFUH/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer3;
    var clickCount = 0;
    $('#targetDIV_three').click(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(timer3);
        srcToGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3.gif";
        srcTonormalGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3_bg.gif";
        if (clickCount == 0) $('#divthree_three').attr('src', srcToGif2);
        clickCount++;
        timer3 = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $("#divthree_three").attr('src', srcTonormalGif2);
            clickCount = 0;
        }, 2000);
        timer3();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it works for the first time. But if you continue clicking the black border box then you will see it is not ending or starting from the first frame.The animated gif is total 1 second loop.